# Problema al encontrar imagen al compilar en python

Tags: python, tkinter, imagen, pyinstaller

Estoy programando en python con tkinter algo sencillo para ABM de productos, mi problema radica al armar el ejecutable con pyinstaller.
Al ejecutar el exe se genera una excepcion que no se encuentra la imagen que uso en la aplicacion

> _tkinter.TclError: couldn't open "C:\Users\diego\Desktop\Pipes2\dist\main\pipes.png": no such file or directory

El bloque de codigo donde cargo la imagen es el siguiente:

```
def cargar_imagen(self):
 self.ruta_scrypt = sys.argv[0]
 self.ruta_proyecto = os.path.dirname(self.ruta_scrypt)
 self.ruta_img = os.path.join(self.ruta_proyecto,"pipes.png")
 ancho = 400
 alto = 450
 self.imagen = tk.PhotoImage(file=self.ruta_img)
 self.imagen = self.imagen.subsample(round(self.imagen.width() / ancho), round(self.imagen.height() / alto))
 self.et_img = tk.Label(self.ventana, image=self.imagen)
```

Para crear el .exe uso esta sentencia:

> pyinstaller --onedir --windowed --add-data="dbconector.py:dbconector.py" --add-data="pipes.png:pipes.png" --add-data=".venv:.venv" --icon="img/pipes.ico" main.py

No comprendo donde esta el error!!
Desde ya gracias!

Comment: Te aseguraste de que la imagen esté en el directorio mencionado en el error?

Comment: Que tal, has verificado que la imagen se encuentre en la ruta exacta que te marca el log?

Comment: buenas, perdon por tardar en responder. La imagen esta en el raiz del proyecto, el error se da al armar el ejecutable, no probe poner la misma imagen en la carpeta main que me crea ( no se me ocurrio )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probe hacer esto, poner la imagen en la carpeta dist/main que me creo.
Problema solucionado